# change back button text of navigation view in sencha touch

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

can I dynamically change "back button" text in navigation view ?? Please share sample code around the same.

I don't want to use :useTitleForBackButtonText - as my title has special characters that appear in the back button.

How do I manually set the back button text - something like

this.getNavBar().getbackbutton().setText ???

I tried

this.getAppNav().getNavigationBar().setBackButton('{'align: 'left', ui: 'back', hidden: true'}')

it gives a "unexpected identifier" error

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.Bar-cfg-backButton give more info on setBackButton method that is private !!

Answer (score 0):

I created top navigation button as view in my app

**TopNavigationView**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TopNavigationView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'topnavigationview',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.Img'
    ],
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype:'toolbar',
                docked:'top',
                height: 44,
                scrollable: false,
                layout:{
                    type:'hbox',
                    pack:'center',
                    align:'center'
                },
                items:[

                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        iconCls: 'settings',
                        name: 'btnSetting'
                    },   

                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        cls: 'btnBackCls',
                        name: 'btnBack'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'spacer'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'label',
                        name: 'lblViewDescription'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'spacer'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:'button',
                        cls: 'btnLogoutCls',
                        name: 'btnLogout'
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

TestController

I created the function, which would dynamically change the title bar / Show or hide the backbutton

```
setTopNavigationBarValues : function() {
        //Configure top navigation bar
        var lblViewDescriptionValue = Ext.ComponentQuery
                .query('label[name=lblViewDescription]');
        for (var i = 0; i < lblViewDescriptionValue.length; i++) {
            lblViewDescriptionValue[i].setHtml('TEST');
            lblViewDescriptionValue[i].setCls('toolbarTitleCls');
        }
        var btnBack = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[name=btnBack]');
        for (var j = 0; j < btnBack.length; j++) {
            btnBack[j].show();
        }
        var btnSetting = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button[name=btnSetting]');
        for (var j = 0; j < btnSetting.length; j++) {
            btnSetting[j].hide();
        }
    },
```

By calling this.setTopNavigationBarValues(); inside the controller

Finally include this topnagivationview through out your project i.e inside the views

**Subview.js**

```
     {
          xtype: 'topnavigationview'
      },
```

Comment: This is best practice. follow this

Comment: I have implemented navigation view for the navigation stack, this seems to be mimicking a navigation bar - not an extension to navigation view ?

Comment: How do I manually set the back button text - something like ? for this just have 2 images for backbutton change in runtime using cls